# Is this the correct way of implementing a dummy node? My code is not working as I intend it to

Tags: java, list, linked-list

```
public class LinkyList<T> implements ListInterface<T> {

  private Node firstNode = new Node(null);            // Reference to first node of chain
  private int  numberOfEntries;

  public LinkyList() {
    initializeDataFields();
  } // end default constructor

  public void clear() {
    initializeDataFields();
  } // end clear
```

Comment: What's the relation between a node and the LinkyList?

Comment: You'll have to explain how you intend it to work and how it is actually working. Also, I'm pretty sure that I understand what you mean by a "dummy node", but there is no universal definition of that term. You'll need to explain what your dummy node is supposed to be used for.